# RDLC report - hiding columns if data is empty

Tags: c#, .net, reporting, rdlc

I have a rdlc report, working on Visual Studio 2010. I want to hide columns that have no data, by using the expression

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!column_header.Value), True, False)
```

(**column_header** is the column's header I want to hide). OK, empty columns are not displayed... But another problem has appeared: the columns in which the first field is empty, not shown. This is strange, and I see nothing wrong with the above expression.

Any help?

Comment: Pretty certain `=IFF(IsNothing(Fields!column_header.Value), True, False)` is the same as `IsNothing(Fields!column_header.Value)`. Also It would appear to me that the reason it is hiding the columns where the first row has no data is because that expression is only checking to see if the header has data not all rows.

Comment: @Shelby115 Yes, you're right about those expressions, both are the same. But, you say that expressions checks if the headers have data.. Headers have data, and I understand that the expression calculates whether **THE COLUMN** has data, not **THE COLUMN HEADER**... I'm right? Or I'm wrong?

Comment: @Shelby115 I finally used the following expression: **=Sum(Fields!column_header.Value, "data_set_name") = 0**. This worked for me and hides all colums that have no data.

Comment: Post it as the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally used the following expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!column_header.Value, "data_set_name") = 0.
```

This worked for me and hides all colums that have no data.